# I have a problem with Web Parsing in python

Tags: python, parsing

I decided to do some exercises in web parsing in Python and I came across a problem which I cannot solve.
In short I have to take information from website called 'pointercrate.com/demonlist/' from first 10 pages and link changes very briefly, only adding 1 in the end of the link (demonlist/1) and so on.

Since I need to take information from different pages I tried code like so

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload = {'demonlist/': 1}
url = 'https://pointercrate.com/'
while payload['demonlist/'] < 11:
    r = requests.get(url, params=str(payload))
    text = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('h1', id='demon-heading')
    print(title)
    payload['demonlist/'] += 1
```

I also tried to write payload = 1 but it gave me an error that I could not mix string with non-string.

No matter what it prints none. I don't know what else to do and I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you want the `params` parameter. You need to modify `url` instead. Ex: `r = requests.get("{url}demonlist/{payload['demonlist/']}")`

Comment: `payload` can just be an integer: `for payload in range(1, 11): r = requests.get(f"https://pointercrate.com/demonlist/{payload}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` parameter of `get()` will help you construct a url like `foo.com?param=1` (parameters form the query string) rather than `foo.com/param/1`. To build the latter, it might be better to construct the `url` with string `format()`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pointercrate.com/demonlist/{page}'
for page in range(1, 10):
    response = requests.get(url=url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('h1', {"id":"demon-heading"})
    print(title.text)
```